# Infuriating gap: How do you get rid of a gap between IMG and surrounding content

Tags: html, css, image

<strike>Been trying for hours, and can seem to find out how to remove that 'white gap' illustrated here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7117445/temp/gap.jpg</strike>

website in question: http://www.jwschultzconstruction.com/staging/index.php

Please help!

*Edited Question after Answer:*

How do you get rid of a gap between IMG and surrounding content? (answer below)

similar to this question: [HTML Strict & CSS: How do I close the gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608357/html-strict-css-how-do-i-close-the-gap)

Comment: Ugh table based layouts. Angry face

Comment: unfort, i'm cleaning up someone else's website. :)

Comment: This question's title made me laugh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the header image display:block

The only style block effecting this currently is:

```
table tr td a img {
    [...]
}
```

So you can add:

```
table tr td a img {
    [...]
    display:block;
}
```

That, or add a class to the image like:

```
<img src="images/banner2.jpg" class="headerImage">
```

And then add a new style block of:

```
.headerImage { display:block; }
```

Comment: phew... bingo... Thanks Matthew and Jeff... I can go take a shower now. ha.

Comment: Display block is the best option, but when you need to have inline images you can also use a really small line-height, like line-height: 0.01em. I believe the issue is caused by the font descender height of an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this will help, so take it as a caveat ... try zeroing out padding and margins in your a tag inside the td box.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this :

```
 table tr td a img {
      margin-bottom:-3px;
 }
```

Might need some additional cleanup due to the table based layout.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is set border = 0 on the image and then set a max-height style on the td that contains the image.  It could also be in your css on your 4th element (table tr td a img)... if you don't have a border, get rid of those 3 styles and add `border:none;`

Have you tried using a firefox add on called firebug?  It makes a huge difference.